# Disable combo box list

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I want to disable a combo box dropdown list from showing in VB.NET and then enable it. How can I do this? The default value of the cbo box should be enabled for typing. 
Thanks

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this: `disable a combo box dropdown list from showing in VB.NET and then enable it`? Include screenshots, code, whichever helps explain your intent.

Answer (score 1):

After Searching for same to disable combo box in vb .net cant find good answer which help...
so i tried some thing like this

1st thing to do while disabling

```
combobox1.enabled=false
combobox1.beginupdate
```

2nd thing to do while enabling

```
combobox1.enabled=true
combobox1.endupdate
```

its looks simple and i dont found any problem but i have doubt may it effect any excecution speen or other object

Answer (score 0):

> I want to disable a combo box dropdown list from showing in VB.NET and then enable it.

Ok, use the `.Visible` property....

> The default value of the cbo box should be enabled for typing

Oh.... then.

### The bad news.

You can't.

### The good news.

You simply put a textbox on top of the combobox. When the dropdown should be disable, make the combobox invisible and show the textbox.

```
'Goodbye Combo

Private Sub HideComboButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles HideComboButton.Click

comboBox.Visible = False
txtBox.Visible = True

End Sub

'Hello Combo

Private Sub ShowComboButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ShowComboButton.Click

comboBox.Visible = True
txtBox.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Hm..I appreciate the effort, but my cbo control is Databound and will create further problems with this method.. :(

Comment: @nectarines: like I said, please include all relevant details in your question. You want an answer without providing details and then you don't like this answer because of some details you did not provide.

Comment: @nectarines Wether you like my answer or not, the information you should remember from it is that what you're trying to do with the combobox is not possible. You can always create a new user control that inherits ComboBox and make it do what you want. I highly doubt that this is the easy solution though...

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. So it's not possible to disable the dropdown action.

Comment: No. You can't cancel the DropDown event of the ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Enabled method eg `comboBox1.Enabled = False`
 Tellme how that works out for you

Answer (score 0):

Try using dropdownstyle, simple can be used to remove list by manually closing the list in designer, then u can switch between dropdown and simple to achieve what you need.